# How to next and previous in firebase when multiple OrderByChild have same Value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I would like to get Most Popular posts with highest number of UpVotes one after another.

```
this.nextPostObservableList=  this.af.database.list('/listOfPost',{
  query :{
    orderByChild : 'postUpvote',
    limitToLast : 2,
    endAt : this.currentPost.postUpvote
  }
});
```

In this case if I orderByChild with postUpvote, I am able to navigate one after another. But if Multiple Posts have same upVote count then I am not able to navigate (Greater than 2 as per above code snippet). Beyond post2 in the below scenario. Please suggest a solution.

```
{
  "post1" : {
    "postUpvote" : 10,
    "postname" : "sample 1"
  },
  "post2" : {
    "postUpvote" : 10,
    "postname" : "Sample 2"
  },
  "post3" : {
    "postUpvote" : 20,
    "postname" : "sample3"
  },
  "post4" : {
    "postUpvote" : 10,
    "postname" : "sample4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... the Firebase SDKs have a `endAt` that takes an extra parameter (the key of the item to start at) for this purpose. I'm not sure if that's wrapped in AngularFire2 though.

Comment: Hi Frank as per documentation key param in endAt is only Valid if is OrderBy is done using priority . :( . [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've tested the key param  with orderByChild(). Can you give it a try?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Yep, the optional parameters for `startAt` and `endAt` are not supported in AngularFire2: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/362 (and the relevant source is [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts#L72-L78))

Comment: Yes its seems it is not supported yet . Let me try using firebase javascript sdk directly .

Answer (score 3):

Support for the optional `key` parameter that can be passed to `startAt` was [added in AngularFire2 `2.0.0-beta.7`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/821). At that time, the Firebase SDK documentation for `endAt` and `equalTo` stated that the optional `key` parameter for those methods could be used only when ordering by priority.

The documentation has since been updated and states that it is supported when ordering child, value or priority.

A [PR](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/821) adding support for the `key` parameter for AngularFire2 when using `endAt` or `equalTo` has been merged, so the next release will support the specifying a `key` when ordering by child and using `endAt`.

To specify the optional `key`, you would use an object literal containing the `value` and the `key`, so your query to retreive the current post and its preceding post would be something like this:

```ts
this.nextPostObservableList = this.af.database.list('/listOfPost', {
  query :{
    orderByChild : 'postUpvote',
    limitToLast : 2,
    endAt : {
      value : this.currentPost.postUpvote,
      key : this.currentPost.postUpvote.$key
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this case supported for empty string value? Meaning elements that have value regardless value itself, and starting/ending by given key parameter. (one test I did was unsuccessful, data returned contained elements from the start of the list, not from given key)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying re: empty strings, as an empty string is a valid value. If it's not working for you, you could ask a question on SO or raise an issue on GitHub. Either way, I'll likely see it. There's unlikely to be enough space in these comments to discuss it.

Comment: Getting exception that endAt and startAt cannot take object as argument .

Comment: The optional key was added for `startAt` in [2.0.0-beta-7](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/821) and for `endAt` in [2.0.0-beta-8](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/838). Please make sure you have the most recent version (2.0.0-beta-8) installed.